# Pulling data from Azure SQL Database to put through the Google API

Tags: android, asp.net, azure, hashmap, google-api

I currently have an Azure SQL Database with various columns, the ones i am focusing on are

FacebookID, Longitude and latitude.

I have an Android app with an ArrayList of Users (A user class basically maps the columns into variables so we can pass user objects around.)

I am wanting to take the information in the 3 columns and push the longitude and latitude through the Google Distance Matrix of the Google API. The distance result from the origin (the origin would be a user of the app) i would want to put into a hashmap of (facebooKID, distanceFromOriging) and send that back to the Android App for it to be extracted and put into a list_View_Activity.

I am currently trying to find an appropriate method to do this and am looking towards using ASP.NET, is this a good approach or would there be a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do this.  Implement a webapi using MVC hosting it on Azure websites (there is a free version).  Make rest calls from your android app into the webapi passing the user's longitude and latitude info.  Your webapi can calculate the distance using google api and send it back.

Info on Webapis: http://www.asp.net/web-api
azure websites: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/web/